# Check If Image Exists Running Into CORS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to check whether an image exists using the below function but keep running into a CORS error. These images are not being sent from a server so I cannot add the regular Access-Control headers. These images are in a local folder and I just need to check whether a specified image is there.

The current code:

```
function isInFolder(url)
    {
      var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
      http.open('HEAD', url, false);
      http.send();
      return http.status!=404;
    }
```

The Error:

```
scripts.b0f3172f.js:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/robertgrzesik/Documents/Development/AngularJS/Templates_Base/dist/assets/product1/content1/info/1.png. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

The logic I'm trying to do:

```
// Assets can be images or videos
if(isInFolder(myAsset)) {
  myAssetArray.push(myAsset);
}
```

Comment: You can't do XHR over `file://`...

Comment: Which language used in backend??

Answer (score 5):

This ended up being the optimal solution for doing this (without a web server):

```
      var fileURL = "assets/"+scope.productDirectory+"/content1/info/"+x+".png";
      imageExists(fileURL, function(exists, url) {
        if(exists) {
          scope.contentOneSequence.push(url);
        }
      });

     function imageExists(url, callback) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() { callback(true, url); };
      img.onerror = function() { callback(false, url); };
      img.src = url;
    }
```

Comment: A BIG thank you! I was hitted by CORS too, and didn't want to call a PHP script to bypass CORS. This is the best sollution!

Answer (score 1):

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

The error you are getting is pretty self-explanatory. It seems like your script is trying to access directly your filesystem and that's not allowed.

You should be serving your assets using a local development webserver.